# Trouble with the concept of captured variables in objective-c blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've read the `str` variable here will be READ-ONLY inside the block.
But when I called the `appendString` method on it, the variable `str` is modified! How?

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hi, My name is "];
int k=2;
void (^testBlock)(void) = ^(void)
{
    k = k*2; //Error as expected    
    [str appendString:@"Mickey Mouse"]; //no Error!!
}

testBlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

One can say that block doesn't allow to change pointers (addresses), but allows to modify object values (not values of variables storing pointers to objects).

For example, you can change mutable objects like mutable strings (append strings) and mutable arrays (insert/update/remove). But you can't re-assign pointer to an immutable array within block without `__block` modifier.

Mutable objects here behave similar to properties/ivars within block.

Comment: That's a pretty bad way of describing it.  A pointer *is* a value.  Your distinction is confusing.

Comment: @Avi, pointer in NOT a value. Pointer points to the address where one can store any value (byte sequence). Having the pointer to the mutable object you can change the object itself easily within block

Comment: If you really think that a pointer is not a value, you need to go back and read some fundamental texts on the C language.  (To be pedantic, the memory address stored in the memory address referred to by a variable name is the value, but being pedantic doesn't really provide clarity in this instance.)

Comment: To quote the C11 draft standard: *A pointer type describes an object whose **value** provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.*

Comment: Pointer can store another pointer as value but it has nothing common with the discussed problem.

Comment: It has everything to do with the discussed problem.  That you think otherwise demonstrates that you are as confused as the poster, even if your confusion is on a different point.  You can't modify a function-scoped variable in a block because they are stored on the stack, and the stack frame may disappear before the block is executed.  When you use the `__block` modifier, the compiler takes care to make sure the variable will be available for the block to modify, but doesn't otherwise change scope semantics.  *continued*

Comment: The value of the variable is captured by the block, which means that if that value is a pointer, the object will be retained.  The object isn't captured by the block, and it's not on the stack.  It's just like any other object that can be messaged, using any available reference.

Comment: To summarize and recall my point in very simple words needed here as answer, local variable stores the pointer to object (its address) and one can't change it within block. But one can modify object (mString value for example) - not the value stored in the local variable (which is a pointer/object address).

Comment: That's a much better answer.

Comment: @Malex Got it! May I know from where you've read this because I've read the entire programming guide for Blocks, yet couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `str` doesn't get modified, it still has the same value - i.e. it points to the same memory address. Try `NSLog(@"%p",str)` to see it for yourself.

What does change with the call to `appendString:` is the contents stored at the address the `str` pointer refers to. The pointer value doesn't change, and this is why it seems that you can manipulate the value of `str`.

As an exercise, try adding a class `Person` and using an instance of it instead of a string. You can go and change various properties of that object, but still operate on the same instance.

Comment: Got it! May I know from where you've read this because I've read the entire programming guide for Blocks, yet couldn't figure it out!

Comment: @Viki this is not related to blocks necessarily but to the way pointers work. A variable holding a memory address (aka a pointer) can  stay the same, but the contents at that memory address change. This doesn't mean the variable itself changes, as the variable is merely a pointer to a memory location, and not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 10;

/*within the block */
a = a/5; 
//prohibited without a __block storage specifier
```

Now see this,

```
 int a =10;
    int *b= &a;



/*within the block */
    *b = (*b)/5; 
    //No Error. The value at the address was only changed but the pointer b is still pointing to the same address viz &a
```